# nodenv: command not found while trying to create virtualenv in node

Tags: node.js, npm, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtualenv in a node.js project to manage nodejs dependancies like grunt, bower, etc.

Trying to use nodeenv for that.

But its not getting recognized.
I did both `npm install nodeenv` and with `-g` flag as well. The dependancy is installed in my node_modules as well, still getting this error.

Comment: What are you trying to achive? Just to create a file from which you can load environment variables?

Comment: An environment from where I can load build dependancies like bower, grunt

Answer (score 1):

Had to install python in my system, and then `pip install nodeenv` to make it work(for windows).

Linux users can directly `sudo apt-get install nodeenv` to get nodeenv and start working with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
➜  ~ npm install nodeenv -g
+ nodeenv@1.0.0
added 1 package in 2.519s

╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                     │ 
│   Update available 5.6.0 → 6.4.1    │
│       Run npm i npm to update       │
│                                     │
╰─────────────────────────────────────╯

➜  ~ nodeenv   myenv   
 * Install prebuilt node (10.10.0) ..... done.
```

after this you need to activate node virtualenv

```
➜  ~ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) ➜  ~
```

now you  install all your node modules.

remember to activate your virtualnev whenever you need to use those modules.

you can deactivate your virtualenv with below command

```
(myenv) ➜  ~ deactivate_node
➜  ~
```

Comment: Yeah the flow explained here is correct, but the problem was that nodeenv wasn't getting recognised by the system after npm install